# split each line in a text file into new text files via command line

Tags: bash, shell, split

I have a text file with 30 lines. I would like to split it up by line where each line will be in a new text file.

I used this command in the command line but didnt get any useful output except the exact same 30 line file but just renamed as "xaa" :

```
split -l 1 mytextfile.txt
```

Am i doing something wrong here?

Comment: what does `file mytextfile.txt` return?

Comment: It returns the same file, but renamed as xaa.txt

Comment: I thought i was supposed to get 30 new text files where each file contains one line of text?

Comment: @jenn `file` is a utility that shows file type. When you run `file mytextfile.txt`, `file` will print a line like "mytextfile.txt: ASCII text, with CR line terminators". 1_CR is asking what it shows for your file.

Comment: Well, obviously that's irrelevant now that you posted your actual command. Amusingly, the first command you posted, `split -l 2 mytextfile.txt`, would almost have worked.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're using the `-l` argument incorrectly. The value you pass in with `-l` is the number of lines to put into each piece. So you're taking a 30 line file and splitting into ... a single 30 line file.

You need to do `split -l 1 mytextfile.txt`

Comment: It worked for me. I created a 30 line file, did `split -l 1`, and it created files `xaa` through `xbd`.

Comment: I realized that the problem was me copying from a csv file to a text file.

Comment: and this is required:%s/^V^M/^V^M/g

Comment: I am getting a new line at the end of each file , what should be done to remove it ?

Answer (score 2):

Try awk

```
cat  mytextfile.txt  |  awk '{ print $0 > "my_splittet_textfile_"NR".txt"}'
```